# How to access the physical Bundled and Minified js / css created by BundleConfig class

Tags: javascript, c#, css, sharepoint, optimization

I am looking to use System.Web.Optimization / the BundleConfig class to bundle javascript and css files during build and then to have a build task copy this file to a specified location. The problem is that I am not sure how to access to the physical files or if it is even possible to access them at compile time.

The bigger picture is that I would like use this approach to keep javascript / css files in a visual studio project and have a process copy files to SharePoint as opposed to using SPD [the horror] for designing and editing and source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear possible with the Bundling class.

I have accomplished my task by using a gulp script to bundle, minify and run a shell script that deploys files using the CSOM.